# Trimming CSVs in Node JS

Tags: node.js, csv, npm

I've downloaded a CSV using Node JS.

Looking to trim the top 4 rows and bottom 3 rows from the csv.
(Summary Rows)

All current modules only provide ability to skip headers.
The script will be run once a day and the length of the csv will change whereas the trim requirements will not.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're trimming the "bottom" rows (and you don't know how long the file is), you'll need to buffer the whole file. This is an easy to do it though using core readline.

```
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

const lineread = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('file.csv'),
});

let lines = [];
lineread.on('line', line => lines.push(line) );
lines = lines.slice( 4, lines.length-2 ); // slice(start,end)
```

Now you've got it all in lines, and just send that to your CSV parser library.

Comment: It states that "a" is undefined.

Comment: @HenryMathias fixed, typo.